# Перенос блока на новую строку

Tags: html, css

Код:

```
<ul>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico1"></i><span>Быстрый</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico2"></i><span>Огромное количество задач</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico3"></i><span>Оптимизированный</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico4"></i><span>Множество возможностей</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico5"></i><span>Автоматические обновления</span></li>
</ul>
```

-

```
.sprite {
        background-image: url(upload/sprite.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block; // если Inline или inline-block, то пропадают изображения
        margin-bottom:15px; // не влияет на выравнивание
    }

    .sprite-easy {
        width: 34px;
        height: 32px;
        background-position: -5px -5px
    }

    .sprite-ico1,
    .sprite-ico2,
    .sprite-ico3,
    .sprite-ico4,
    .sprite-ico5 {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px
    }

    .sprite-ico1 {
        background-position: -49px -5px
    }

    .sprite-ico2 {
        background-position: -91px -5px
    }

    .sprite-ico3 {
        background-position: -133px -5px
    }

    .sprite-ico4 {
        background-position: -175px -5px
    }

    .sprite-ico5 {
        background-position: -217px -5px
    }

    .sprite-pin {
        width: 36px;
        height: 32px;
        background-position: -259px -5px
    }

    .sprite-saturn {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        background-position: -305px -5px
    }

    .sprite-settings {
        width: 33px;
        height: 32px;
        background-position: -347px -5px
    }
```

sprite.png:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, к примеру, заяц и "Быстрый" должны быть в одной строке. Как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.sprite {
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVq2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 display: block;
}

.clearfix {clear:left; list-style-type:none; margin-bottom:10px;}
.clearfix i.sprite {float:left;}
.clearfix span {display:block; margin-left:42px; font-size:22px; line-height:32px; font-family:Arial;}

.sprite-ico1,
.sprite-ico2,
.sprite-ico3,
.sprite-ico4,
.sprite-ico5 {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px
}

.sprite-ico1 {background-position: -49px -5px}
.sprite-ico2 {background-position: -91px -5px}
.sprite-ico3 {background-position: -133px -5px}
.sprite-ico4 {background-position: -175px -5px}
.sprite-ico5 {background-position: -217px -5px}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico1"></i><span>Быстрый</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico2"></i><span>Огромное количество задач</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico3"></i><span>Оптимизированный</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico4"></i><span>Множество возможностей</span></li>
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico5"></i><span>Автоматические обновления</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {}

ul > li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin:25px 0;
}
ul > li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVq2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: -16px;
 }
ul > li:first-child:before {background-position: -49px -5px;}
ul > li:nth-child(2):before {background-position: -91px -5px;}
ul > li:nth-child(3):before {background-position: -133px -5px;}
ul > li:nth-child(4):before {background-position: -175px -5px;}
ul > li:nth-child(5):before {background-position: -217px -5px;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Быстрый</li>
    <li>Огромное количество задач</li>
    <li>Оптимизированный</li>
    <li>Множество возможностей</li>
    <li>Автоматические обновления</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Новое, это хорошо забытое старое, используйте возможности "табличной" вёрстки:

```css
.sprite {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVq2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
ul {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
li {
  display: table-row;
}
i,
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
i {
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.sprite-ico1 {
  background-position: -49px -5px
}

.sprite-ico2 {
  background-position: -91px -5px
}

.sprite-ico3 {
  background-position: -133px -5px
}

.sprite-ico4 {
  background-position: -175px -5px
}

.sprite-ico5 {
  background-position: -217px -5px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico1"></i><span>Быстрый</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico2"></i><span>Огромное количество задач</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico3"></i><span>Оптимизированный</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico4"></i><span>Множество возможностей</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix"><i class="sprite sprite-ico5"></i><span>Автоматические обновления</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например добавить свойство `display: inline-block;`

Добавить класс к `<ul class="myList">`

И стиль:

```
.myList > li * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`inline-block` означает что выбранный блок нужно выводить в одну линию.

Но это только выравнивание, далее нужно будет равнять внутренности